# Best practice for wrapping a third party service in a library

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, design-patterns

I am interested in writing a library for a third party API I am using and I need some advice. The average use of the library will involve several api calls in one request. For example, one api call to grab a user from the third party service, and then another call to use that user to grab his/her photos. Each API call will get its own library method wrapper with additional logic to handle errors/timeouts, but my biggest question is whether the library should be made as a singleton that contains state or just as a series of class methods.

For example:

```
user_id = ThirdParty.get_user("abc@gmail.com")
photos = ThirdParty.get_photos(user_id)
```

OR

```
thirdpartyservice = ThirdPartyService.new("abc@gmail.com")
photos = thirdpartyservice.get_photos
```

These doesn't have to be the exact deseign of the library, but I just am confused about the pros/cons of each approach. Any help would be amazing!

Btw, I am using ruby!

Comment: For the question related to making library as a singleton, it is good to make it as a static class with static methods because I understand that state of the library class need not be maintained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would have the library contain the state as this reduces the complexity of code on the user side(and that's what API are supposed to do, increase simplicity). With this approach, the user doesn't have to keep track of that user_id since the library is keeping state of that.

If the user really wanted their user_id (or any other data that the library stores), you can just create an `attr_reader` in your library to expose that data.

To add fleixiblity for the get_photos method, you can do something like:

```
class ThirdPartyService

  def get_photos(user_id=@id_stored_in_library)
    # do work
  end

end
```

This way it defaults to the stored id, however it adds flexibility in that the user can specify the userid if he so chooses.

Answer (score 2):

You need state (host, etc) and behavior based on that state so you should use objects, not one singleton object.

As mentioned, you should not name methods like `get_photos`, just `photos`.

Comment: I agree with the naming standards. In terms of the host, etc, all of that info is constant. The host and oauth token info is the same for every call. Do you still think I should not use a singleton?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best practice is using provider and services for the ability to not be tied down to a specific service provider. Instead of simply wrapping the library you may want to abstract it a bit and by default only allow a single service provider.

Although inheritance isn't really needed in a dynamic/duck typed language like Ruby this may help concrete the 'why'.

```
class MailProvider 

  def initialize(args); raise "Not Implemented"; end

  def send_mail(args); raise "Not Implemented"; end

end

class SendGridService < MailProvider

  def initialize(args)
    # Use args here
  end

  def send_mail(args)
    # Use SendGrid's API or Gem here
  end

end
```

Then, in your code you can have something like this:

```
config.mail_provider = SendGridService.new({
  username: ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
  password: ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD']
})

config.mail_provider.send_mail({ subject: 'woot', message: 'Look ma, I did it!' })
```

Then six months later when your users love your Gem/library but want MailChimp support you can simply create a second service 'MailChimpService' and allow your clients to use the new provider.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of get_ set_ methods will be better to use getters and setters. It is ruby standard (not sure, but get_ and set_ methods I saw only once in ruby code).

If you don't need to save some state between requests, make it static. But it depends on many factors. Can you tell us what API you need to wrap ?